# Why won't my textarea update through Ajax after entry has been re-saved to database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery

I am updating a simple `text_area` in Rails using Ajax:

**application.js**:

```
$("#invoice_project_id").change(function() {
    var value=$(this).val();
    $.get('/invoices/get_recipient', {project_id= : value}  function(response) {
        $('#invoice_recipient').val(response);
    })
});​
```

**get_recipient.js**:

```
$('#invoice_recipient').val("<%= @recipient.to_s.gsub!(/\n/, '\n') %>");
```

**invoices_controller.rb**:

```
def get_recipient
  project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
  @recipient = project.person.address
end
```

The code works great and replaces the value of the `recipient` text_area with the correct address, depending on what `project` gets chosen in the select menu.

The problem is that it works only with the `addresses` that already exist in the database. (I am using the [**Rails Faker gem**](http://faker.rubyforge.org) to populate my database.) The moment I **re-save** a `person`'s `address` manually in my Safari browser, the text_area won't get updated through Ajax anymore when I try to do so using the above code.

How is this possible?

I am already escaping the newline characters using the `gsub!` method above, so I can't think of anything else I could do.

Can anybody help?

Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, turns out that the carriage returns in the addresses were causing the trouble.

These carriage returns are only created when updating an address in the browser through a `textarea`. The Faker gem mentioned above creates newline characters but no carriage returns.

I saw this only when inspecting my database records on the console because `\r` and `\n` characters are invisible anywhere else I looked.

So in my particular case I just needed to remove the carriage returns in my **model** like so:

```
address.gsub!("\r", "")
```

I was not able to do this in any of my javascript files.

Just one simple line of code, but several **hours** of work for me. So hopefully somebody else will benefit from this.